# Python TypeError: Mapping the values of two lists into key-value pairs in a new one container list

Tags: python

I've two lists/arrays `titles` and `descriptions` as below:

```
 titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
 descriptions = ['description1', 'description2', 'description3']
```

I need to make one list/array `topic` containing both of them as dictionaries/objects key-value pairs as below:

```
topics [
   {
     'title': 'title1',
     'description': 'description1'
   },
   {
     'title': 'title2',
     'description': 'description2'
   },
   {
     'title': 'title3',
     'description': 'description3'
   }
]
```

I've tried to do that like in PHP or JS:

```py
    titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
    descriptions = ['description1', 'description2', 'description3']

    topics = []

    for i in range(len(titles)):
        topics[i]['title'] = titles[i]
        topics[i]['description'] = descriptions[i]
```

But I got that error:

`topics[i]['title'] = titles[i]`
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

So how shoud I do that stuff in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a list-comprehension using `zip`:

```
[{'title': x, 'description': y} for x, y in zip(titles, descriptions)]
```

**Example**:

```
titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
descriptions = ['description1', 'description2', 'description3']

print([{'title': x, 'description': y} for x, y in zip(titles, descriptions)])
# [{'title': 'title1', 'description': 'description1'}, 
#  {'title': 'title2', 'description': 'description2'}, 
#  {'title': 'title3', 'description': 'description3'}]
```